# create a virtualenv with multiple versions of python

Tags: pip

Is it possible to create a virtualenv with multiple versions of python?

This would allow the user to pip install both `python3` and `python2` packages (using `pip2` and `pip3`).

The following doesn't work

```
virtualenv -p python2.7 -p python3.5 venv
```

Answer (score 1):

`virtualenv` does not provide creating virtual environments with multiple versions of Python.

You can setup virtual environment for one interpreter only and `-p` takes only one argument that can be 'python3' or 'python2.7'.

> The Python interpreter to use, e.g., –python=python2.5 will use the
>   python2.5 interpreter to create the new environment. The default is
>   the interpreter that virtualenv was installed with (like
>   /usr/bin/python)
>
> Source: [Docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/reference.html#cmdoption-p)